Can I set the background-color of two spans on adjacent lines, so the color also fills the space between the lines?
I have two spans on adjacent lines, with their background-color set. Unfortunately this leaves a gap between the two lines:


html {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
}
<pre>
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>



Is it possible, by only changing the style used for span, to extend the colored background vertically so that it fills the gap?
One thing I've tried using is padding: ... 0;, but it's not clear what value to use for ... in order to be robust against changes in font-size and/or line-height.

font-size should be rather little to worry about, when you use a font size-relative length unit ... but I don't think there is anything that could take line-height into account dynamically. But - can't you just make the spans be inline-block ...?

There is a proposal in the CSS Inline layout Level 3 draft for a property and value of inline-sizing: stretch which would, if I've understood it correctly, do exactly what you want. However, I don't think it's close to being implemented anywhere yet, and there's a high probability that the property will be renamed first because of its similarity to the existing but completely different inline-size property.

I think display: inline-block; will do the trick.


html {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
<pre>
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>




Thanks! One issue with this is that if the break between the lines is inside a span, then display: inline-block merges the two lines into one. For example, if the HTML is arranged over five lines instead of four: <pre> <span>line 1 </span><span>line 2 </span> </pre>. Is there a way to fix this so that this HTML also shows two separate lines?

@user200783 Could you provide an example in some HTML sandbox?

You could add a pseudo after element to all but the final span and give that the same background color and if you give it a line height of 1 it will be large enough to cover the gap. Position it just below the span element so any padding is taken care of.


html {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

pre>span {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

pre>span:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1lh;
  background-color: red;
}
<pre>
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>




Making line-height: 1; does that job.


html {
  line-height: 1.15;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
}
<pre>
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>



Another way would be of to remove style from html.


span {
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
<pre>
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>




Add a big vertical padding (1lh should be enough) then use a clip-path to make sure the visible area is equal exactly to 1lh.


html {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 1lh 0;
  clip-path: inset(calc(50% - .5lh - 1px) 0);
  /* the "-1px" is not mandatory but I use it to make sure there is no gap
     due to pixel rounding
  */
}
<pre>
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>

<pre style="font-size: 2em">
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>

<pre style="font-size: 2em;line-height:2">
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>

<pre style="line-height:3">
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>



Here is an overview where I color the padding differently to better understand. You can also disable the clip-path to see what it's doing:


html {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

span {
  background: 
   linear-gradient(red 0 0) content-box,
   blue;
  padding: 1lh 0;
  clip-path: inset(calc(50% - .5lh - 1px) 0);
}
<pre>
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>

<pre style="font-size: 2em">
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>

<pre style="font-size: 2em;line-height:2">
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>

<pre style="line-height:3">
<span>line 1</span>
<span>line 2</span>
</pre>




I would just wrap in a flex div to ensure it always works as expected.


html {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
<pre>
<div class="col">
  <span>line 1</span>
  <span>line 2</span>
</div>
</pre>



